# How do scalars like currrent or amplitude add vectorially and give correct results?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

I have seen in alternating current that values of current and potential difference in different circuits like LR, CR or LCR circuits are found by adding them like vectors.
It also happens with amplitude of waves in wave interference.
**I understand that their values varies as given in the equation**

### I=I<sub>○</sub>sin(ωt)

 **but that does not make them vectors**
Voltage calculation in LCR[image: Voltage in LCR]
Phasor of LCR series[image: Phasor of LCR]
Resultant Amplitude of 2 waves[image: Wave interference amplitude]
Similarly net resistance or impedance to flow of current is found in LCR series as given as under. (The angle between net of capacitive and inductive reactance and resistance is 90° so cos90 becomes zero and that part is removed in formula)
[image: Impedance of LCR circuit]

The best explanation I got was that they are assumed and treated as such using phasors.

I tried to prove that the assumptions are correct by adding them as scalars(as happens in reality) but couldn't find a way.

**So can you add them as scalars or atleast explain & prove what happens that makes scalar additions in reality give same answers as vector addition in assumption?**

Say an LR circuit is taken

Comment: How do you add scalars "like vectors"?

Comment: In LCR circuits the currents in inductor and capacitor are treated as vectors opposing each other and are treated as making an angle phai with current in resistor

Comment: Perhaps treating the quantities like complex numbers would help.

Comment: @user3257842 Treating capacitive and inductive reactance as imaginary resistance sounds good but I am going to need a little more explanation of maybe the physical or mathematical proof

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance#Validity_of_complex_representation